# react native API response check

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, I want to know how I can check the API POST and GET response as we checked the response of the API in networking in react js.

Right now I'm using expo to set up the project and the expo go app to work around

I am sending a POST req and it was showing an error

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

so I want to check the body what response I am sending to the API to fix the issue.

Comment: Please share some code to improve your question. Also explain what have you tried that gave you the mentioned error. Also share the full stack trace of error if available. If you are aksing how to make API request in react-native then you can use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send requests in react-native you use the javascript *fetch* function.

For example:

```
try {
    const response = await fetch("www.yourapi.com", { method: "GET" });

    let data = undefined;

    if (response.status === 200) {
        data = await response.json();
    }

    return data;
} catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err)
}
```